# Restore google cloud notebook after restart

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-shell

How can I restore **google cloud datalab** notebook? 
I can see the notebooks through **ssh**, if I try to find the files with *readlink* command, but I cannot see it with *ls* command and download them to my PC or view it through datalab interface.
When I try to upload a new notebook to that instance, I cannot do it anymore it seems that interface is broken.
Update2: after reconnection I see the newly-added notebooks, but don't see the old ones.
How can I restore the old notebooks?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What kind of restart was it? VM restart? Or just your client? Can you still connect to the Datalab VM by doing `datalab connect <vm_name>`?

Comment: Yes, it was VM restart, and datalab connect does work, but it appears, that datalab interface doesnt't work anymore - please read the update of the question and sorry for my emotions.

Comment: What does "datalab interface doesn't work anymore" mean? Do you see the interface at all?

Comment: Yes, I see. Actually it works, I updated the description. I just don't see old notebooks and saved files with results there. I can see the backups in cloud storage, is it the only way to restore the notebooks?

Comment: gloud commany for copying files doesn't work as well:
gcloud compute copy-files datalab@elitea: /mnt/disks/datalab-pd/datalab/notebooks elitea-notebooks
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) Source(s) must be remote when destination is local.  Got sources: [datalab@elitea:, /mnt/disks/datalab-pd/datalab/notebooks], destination: elitea-notebooks

Comment: and finally, the notebooks from bckups archive on google cloud storage are not readable, because they are not in JSON format:
Unreadable Notebook: /content/datalab/avito/lightfm_install.ipynb NotJSONError("Notebook does not appear to be JSON: u''...",)

Comment: When I wanted to restore it manually, and tried to create new notebook, An error occurred while creating a new notebook.
Unexpected error while saving file: datalab/Untitled Notebook1.ipynb [Errno 28] No space left on device

Comment: Accidentally, after restoring default settings of the VM in the Compute Engine Console, everything appears to be working. Sorry for disturbance!

Answer (score 2):

Accidentally, after restoring default settings of the VM in the Compute Engine Console, everything appears to be working. Sorry for disturbance!